# All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL

Tags: mysql

I get the error `"All parts of a SPATIAL index must be NOT NULL."` when trying to define a spatial index on a nullable geometry column. Is this a limitation of MySQL or would there be a logical reason behind this decision? Because, the response to the feature request below states that MySQL team does not plan to support this.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91464

Answer (score 1):

This is documented:

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual  /  ...  /  CREATE INDEX Statement  /  Spatial Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-spatial)

> Spatial indexes on spatial columns have these characteristics:
>
> ...
>
> - Indexed columns must be NOT NULL.

---

You may try to use some pre-defined constant instead of NULL value. For example, if you use this index for fast search for closest points then this constant may be a coordinate of unreasonably far point.